# 16:8 ratio disrupts with video.js default skin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I am using videojs in my react application. I have wrapper the  in a div which has 16:8 ratio. The problem is video js player doesn't shows up with deafult skin. But I have other code which implements default skin but screws up with 16:8 ration of container div. Here is my code which does not show default skin

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="video-wrapper">
      <video
        id="example_video_1"
        controls="true"
        className="video-js vjs-default-skin"
      >
        <source src={videoSrc} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is what the player looks like

[image]

Here is the style code:

```
.video-wrapper {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.video-wrapper > video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

And this is code with default videojs skin

```
render() {
  var props = blacklist(
    this.props,
    "children",
    "className",
    "src",
    "type",
    "onPlay"
  );

  props.className = cx(
    this.props.className,
    "videojs",
    "video-js vjs-default-skin",
    "vjs-big-play-centered"
  );

  assign(props, {
    ref: "video",
    controls: true
  });

  return (
    <div className="video-wrapper">
      <video {...props}>
        <source src={videoSrc} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here is what it renders (the skin what I want), but it screws the ration of wrapper-div

[image]

What is the problem? How can I bring the default skin via first code?

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to fix your problem

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="video-wrapper">
                <video id="example_video_1" controls="true" data-setup='{}' className="video-js vjs-default-skin">
                    <source src={videoSrc} type="video/mp4"/>
                </video>
            </div>)
    }
```

I hope it works for you 
I will tell you the problem in your first code. 
It does **not** have `data-setup='{}'`
Videojs searches for the video tag which includes a `data-setup='{}'`. Without it I doubt it works (Not for me at least.)

Here is the solution:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="video-wrapper">
                <video id="example_video_1" controls="true" className="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered">
                    <source src={videoSrc} type="video/mp4"/>
                </video>
            </div>)
    }
```

`vjs-big-play-centered` centres the play button

Hope it was helpful